# Dynamic Build Definition in TFS

Tags: xaml, tfs

I'm working with a TFS structure that looks something like:

```
$Root
  - Projects
    -SolutionA
    -SolutionB
    -SolutionC
    -SolutionD
```

I want to set up gated checkins on the server. Each 'Solution' folder contains a separate Visual Studio solution, and work is split up based on these. I've been fiddling around with a build process template for the last couple of hours and have not nearly made the progress that I was hoping to have made.

What I would like to do is have a single build definition that only builds the Solution(s) that corresponds with the checkin being gated at the time of the build kicking off. So, if a checkin only has changes to SolutionA, I only want to build SolutionA (not SolutionB, C, or D). Similarly, if a checkin has changes to both SolutionA and SolutionC, I want to build both A and C, but not B or D.

I'm having trouble figuring out 2 things. First, how do I find which Solution(s) a give checkin has modified? Second, how do I use that information to specify to only build the changed Solution(s)?

**Edit**: If there's a resource out there that explains how to do this, I'm more than happy to read it. I've just not had any luck finding it on my own.

Comment: Top of my head here but perhaps you could turn on incremental builds and then when the check-in (not just gated unless that is what the build def specifies) only the projects \ solutions that have changed will be rebuilt.

Comment: Why would you not want to have one build definition for each individual application? This gets you what you want -- if you change SolutionA and SolutionC, only the build definitions for A and C will run.

Comment: @DanielMann The reason I was wanting to get away from that approach is due to the sheer amount of solutions in this workspace. We're nearing about 100, and I didn't want to create 100 different build definitions. However, I'm getting the feeling that this may be the way to go anyway. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Any news here? Have the same problem. Microsoft looks don't have a solution for that scenario